# Creating hotlinks only on objects that have value using MapBasic?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

In mapbasic I am creating hotlinks with the code below. However when there is no value in the column it creates a hyperlink that doesn't work and this is frustrating for users. Is it possible to only have the hyperlink on records with a value? or at least for those without a value the alias should say "No AsCon found"

```
Map From temptable
mapWinID = FrontWindow()
Set Map Window mapWinID Layer 1 Activate Using "https://server.com/docs/~D"+"As_con_InfoExpert_ID" On Labels Objects Relative Path Off Enable On
Metadata Table temptable SetKey "\ActiveObject\Expr" To ("""https://server.com/docs/~D""+As_con_InfoExpert_ID")
Metadata Table temptable SetKey "\ActiveObject\Mode" To "HOTLINK_MODE_BOTH"
Metadata Table temptable SetKey "\ActiveObject\Relative" To "OFF"
Metadata Table temptable SetKey "\ActiveObject\Enabled" To "TRUE"
Metadata Table temptable SetKey "\ActiveObject\Alias" To ("Open in Infoexpert")
```

Comment: Could you select the data that has the values first into a 'holding' table, then use the MapBasic on that selection?

Comment: I don't this so as the hotlinks are on/off for a whole table and not a selection of one (as far as I know)...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MapInfo Pro 17.0, you can try using the IIf() function to only build an expression for the records with a value:

```
Metadata Table temptable SetKey "\ActiveObject\Expr" To ("IIf(As_con_InfoExpert_ID, ""https://server.com/docs/~D""+As_con_InfoExpert_ID, """")")
```

You might want to check if I have the correct number of quotes in the expression above.